# php stop shell exec on cancel

Tags: php, exec

When I cancel a PHP Script by pressing the browser's "Stop"-Button, it seems that an external binary run by `exec(..)` is not stopped. If the server is configured to not handle more then one script per user, that disables any user activity until the runned command is finished. How cann I tell PHP to kill the executed process when canceled?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582485/kill-mysql-query-on-user-abort/7582527#7582527

Answer (score 1):

In short, with an element of difficulty.

Your browser says to the server "Do this page", server then replies with what it got back when it ran the script. If the client goes away, the server usually still completes the script, irrelvant of wether the browser listens or not.

Only way I can think of is, if the server is UNIX, you can possibly do something to try and work out the PID of your running command,  and if you read http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php you can set things to happen on disconnects. Following on from that you could then having a PID run another command to kill off the command.

However, I wouldnt like to guarentee results.

Comment: "If the client goes away, the server usually still completes the script" seems wrong. PHP is able to cancel the execution if the user closes the connection (should work at least with CGI wrapping I think), that can be disabled using `ignore_user_abort()`. However it seems not to kill `exec(...)` processes.

Comment: The reason a stalling `exec(..)` is not killed is maybe that the kill is only done on a write to the broken output pipe. Thus an user abort doesn't trigger the kill unless the `exec`'d process is generating output.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $command = 'your command' . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!'; 
 exec($command, $output);
 echo $pid = (int)$output[0];
```

Then when you want to kill it:

```
 exec("kill -9 $pid");
```

Answer (score -3):

in webpage use exec to lunch process and hold on to the returned pid.

```
$pid = exec($command);
```

later in your UI check if process ended and if needed allow user to kill process with something like:

```
exec("kill -9 $pid");
```

Since it's started by Apache, Apache should be able to kill it.
I see ajax calls to some sort of REST API, and you should take care not to allow users to kill more then the process they started.

Comment: exec doesn't return a pid as far as I can tell

Comment: $command could be something like "pidof ....", or find some way to identify PID of your "external binary". If you give exact example I will give exact code. PID must be in the output. never said exec will return a PID of the command in exec, but I guess I was not clear about it.