# KILL MySQL queries using PHP if user close the browser or navigate from one page to other page

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli

My website is using onload AJAX. So when the user entering into a page 6 AJAX calls are executed parallel. In middle of the process if user close the browser or navigate to another page I wants to kill the queries.

**Steps to achieve this:**

**1.** Find the Next MySQL query execution ID(The connection identifier) and store it into a session.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html

We need to identify this ID before execute the READ(select) query. Because PHP will execute line by line.

**Problem**

`How do we identify the next connection identifier?`

OR

```
How do we reserve the connection identifier and execute the query on specified identifier?
```

**2**. Execute the query in database.

**3.** If user aborted is identified then kill the MySQL query execution. We can detect the user aborted status in PHP using connection_aborted()/ ignore_user_abort() function.

Use this following command to terminate this query execution:

`KILL ID`

Comment: `I wants to kill the queries`. Why?

Comment: What do you mean "next id"? You can only kill queries that are currently executed, not some "future queries". Am I missing something?

Comment: @BartFriederichs The user is moved from one page to another page but in mysql still six queries are in process

Comment: @Sundar these are long running queries, that take more than few seconds?

Comment: @AlmaDo The next id denotes the future mysql query will execute in that ID

Comment: @BartFriederichs the query is running in 5 crore record DB and the process is little heavy

Comment: @Sundar then I'm lost. Why? Isn't your task to terminate all queries that were run by current script? (i.e. script that received user abort signal)

Comment: @AlmaDo The task to terminate all queries that were run by current script(6 different ajax calls)?

Comment: @Sundar yes. To be more precise, "task to terminate all queries that were done during execution of _this_ script instance" (so for 6 ajax calls there will be 6 processes, obviously)

Comment: Steps to achieve this: to abort some mySQL query from PHP, you need parallel execution in PHP; because otherwise PHP locks until mySQL has completed execution.

Comment: @Alexander We can create one more database connection with root level privileged login. So we can parallel the process using AJAX and PHP. Due to PHP lock only I want to get the connection identifier before executing the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query also returns the current connection identifier

```
SELECT CONNECTION_ID();
```

After receiving this connection identifier we can execute our query on this identifier.

Answer (score 3):

step 1: Get thread id of the MySql connection

```
    $thread_id = mysqli_thread_id($link);
```

step 2: Use ignore_user_abort(); in code

step 3: Check if connection is closed. If yes then kill the thread as follows:

```
        if (connection_aborted() && mysqli_kill($connection_link, $thread_id)) {
           die();
        }
```

Check the accepted solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582485/kill-mysql-query-on-user-abort).